# Why isn't my linked list addition program working for some cases

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, linked-list, reference

So I have a java program to add two numbers, both numbers are represented by 2 different linked lists where each node stores one digit.

I am trying to write a recursive solution where the sum of both linked lists is in the first linked list and that is returned.

example: Linked List 1= 125

Linked List 2=149

Linked List 3 should contain 274(125+149).

My program is here:

```
/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* public class ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode next;
*     ListNode() {}
*     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
*     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
* }
*/
class Solution {

public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
addnums(l1,l2);
Display(l1);
return l1;
}



public static void addnums(ListNode l1, ListNode l2)    // actual work is done here
{

if(l1!=null && l2!=null)
{
l1.val+=l2.val;
if(l1.val>=10)
l1=carryfwd(l1);
addnums(l1.next,l2.next);
}
else if(l1==null && l2!=null)
{
// l1.val=l2.val;
l1=new ListNode(l2.val);
System.out.println("initialized with "+l1.val);
addnums(l1.next,l2.next);
}
}



public static void Display(ListNode l)
{
while(l!=null)
{
if(l.next==null)
System.out.println(l.val+" ");
else
System.out.print(l.val+" ");
l=l.next;
}
}


public static ListNode carryfwd(ListNode l)    // to carryover to the next node
{
l.val%=10;
if(l.next!=null)
{l.next.val+=1;
if(l.next.val>=10)
carryfwd(l.next);
}
else
l.next=new ListNode(1);
return l;
}

}
```

This code doesn't work for

L1={0}

L2={7,3}

, the L1 returned by the addTwoNumbers method is {7} only.

Even though I am appending 3 to L1 in the else part of addnums method.

Please help me understand where my 3 node is getting lost.

You can run this code directly at :    https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Comment: You can (and should) perform self-help on this one. Debugging is a skill that will be useful to you in the future. Make a [mre] that does not require an external website to run. Step through it in a debugger. Additional tips: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Hint: "Even though I am appending 3 to L1" no, that's not quite what you're doing. You can start your investigation there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that when the `else` block kicks in, `l1` is assigned a new value. The caller will not see this change, since `l1` is local variable. So what ever happens after that, is happening on a list that is not connected to the original `l1`.

The deeper problem is that the `addnums` function *cannot* hope to attach new nodes to the first list when all it got was a `null` value.

This is why it is better to stick with the original signature of the `addTwoNumbers` function, which *returns* the resulting list. In that case there is no problem when the first argument happens to be `null`: we can still create the new node and return it.

Another remark is this: when one of the two list nodes is `null` you can then just return the other. Nothing more needs to happen in that case.

So here is a correction, keeping the code you had in the `if` block, which was fine:

```
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        // If one of the arguments is null, return the other
        if (l1 == null) return l2;
        if (l2 == null) return l1;
        // Your original logic:
        l1.val += l2.val;
        if (l1.val >= 10)
            l1 = carryfwd(l1);
        l1.next = addTwoNumbers(l1.next, l2.next);
        return l1;
    }
```

Note that you can gain some speed by replacing recursion with iteration, and keeping the carry in variable that just gets added again in the next iteration.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks